# Card Views in Recyclerview change positions on scrolling.

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recycler view containing card view with custom elements. All is working fine, but when I scroll the list of cards, the card views change positions. How can I control that.

Here is my adapter class.

```
public class ProductAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductAdapter.ProductViewHolder> {

ArrayList<Product> Products = new ArrayList<Product>();


public  ProductAdapter(ArrayList<Product> Products)
{

    this.Products = Products;
}


@Override
public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view_layout,parent,false);

    ProductViewHolder ProductViewHolder = new ProductViewHolder(view);

    return ProductViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Product product = Products.get(position);

        holder.pic.setImageBitmap(product.getBitmap());
        holder.name.setText(product.getName());
        holder.size.setText(product.getSize());
        holder.price.setText(product.getPrice());



}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return Products.size();
}

public static class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private ImageView pic;
    private TextView name,size,price;

    public ProductViewHolder(View view)
    {
        super(view);
        pic = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.pic);
        name  = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        size = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.size);
        price = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: What is the `LayoutManager` that is using the `RecyclerView`?

Comment: LinearLayout Manager @DouglasJunior

Comment: I believe that should not happen in `LinearLayoutManager`, because the `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` change positions to adjust the objects on the screen.

Comment: What am I supposed to do now?

Answer (score 0):

Change the layout_height of the LinearLayout to "wrap_content".
it will working.

Comment: Its very Low quality.

Answer (score -3):

I think u need to Override these methods...

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Comment: What to write in these methods?

Comment: inside ur recyclerview adapter... ProductAdapter

Comment: That is obvious, but what to do inside these methods?